# ffmpeg performance with multiple core cpu and windows

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, multi-core

I call ffmpeg command to generate mp4 using input of mp3 and folder of images

my problem is running 3 instance of ffmpeg cause 8 GB 6 core to be full with 100% cpu this is the command I use , any idea or anything wron with the command i use

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 25 -start_number 1 -i D:\%d.Jpeg -i D:\yyyyy.m4a -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p D:\xxxx.mp4"
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but why *wouldn't* you want the command to utilize all CPU time available to it?

Comment: @slhck for many reasons the server has many background services , I want ffmpeg to use limited resources

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your command or ffmpeg. If you run multiple instances of resource-intensive processes in parallel, you should expect (at least some of) your CPU cores to max out. In fact, one can safely assume that people want to do their transcoding as fast as possible, so it does not make sense at all to have the tool limit its own CPU usage. You want to limit the process using your OS's process scheduler; see the linked question and other resources on the web for that.

Comment: @slhck unfortunately most of them for xp , no server but I get the direction to search thanks a lot

Comment: The `start /affinity` command should work, but I'm not a Windows expert.